# Select node in tree based on sibling

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I've run in to a problem when parsing a node tree. Here's an example XML Document of what I am working with:

```
<result>
    <type>street_address</type>
    <formatted_address>Krasickiego 6, 83-020 Cedry Wielkie, Poland</formatted_address>
    <address_component>
        <long_name>6</long_name>
        <short_name>6</short_name>
        <type>street_number</type>
    </address_component>
    <address_component>
        <long_name>Krasickiego</long_name>
        <short_name>Krasickiego</short_name>
        <type>route</type>
    </address_component>
    <address_component>
        <long_name>Cedry Wielkie</long_name>
        <short_name>Cedry Wielkie</short_name>
        <type>locality</type>
        <type>political</type>
    </address_component>
    <address_component>
        <long_name>Gmina Cedry Wielkie</long_name>
        <short_name>Gmina Cedry Wielkie</short_name>
        <type>administrative_area_level_3</type>
        <type>political</type>
    </address_component>
    <address_component>
        <long_name>Gdańsk County</long_name>
        <short_name>Gdańsk County</short_name>
        <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
        <type>political</type>
    </address_component>
    <address_component>
        <long_name>Pomeranian Voivodeship</long_name>
        <short_name>Pomeranian Voivodeship</short_name>
        <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
        <type>political</type>
    </address_component>
    <address_component>
        <long_name>Poland</long_name>
        <short_name>PL</short_name>
        <type>country</type>
        <type>political</type>
    </address_component>
    <address_component>
        <long_name>83-020</long_name>
        <short_name>83-020</short_name>
        <type>postal_code</type>
    </address_component>
</result>
```

I want to get the country code (PL) and the postal code (83-020) from this tree. I believe I am able to search the tree for nodes that contain the text "country" and "postal_code" and grab the sibling node with the correct name (for example, search for "country" and grab the sibling node named "short_name"), but I am unsure how. Could I get some help headed in the right direction? I am working in C# and using XPath.

Comment: Please add some code showing what you have tried and where exactly the query is failing. This will help the experts here to better answer your question. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for the guidelines. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath query should return the short_name node that's got a sibling node named type with a value of "postal_code":

```
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("result/address_component[type='postal_code']/short_name")
```

Do the same to find the country code:

```
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("result/address_component[type='country']/short_name")
```